# When does $x+y$ divide $2xy+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that, for $a, b$ odd integers with $n-1 = ab$ and $\gcd(a-1,b-1) = 2$, then there exists a linear combination $n = (a-1)x+(b-1)y$ with $x \neq y$ and $x,y > 0$. Letting $A = \frac{a-1}{2}, B = \frac{b-1}{2}$, I need to show that either:

1. $\frac{n}{2} = 2AB+A+B+1$ is not divisible by $A+B$, in which case the guaranteed solution in $x$ and $y$ is valid,
2. If 1. fails for some $a,b$, I can choose different $a$ and $b$ such that 1. holds,
3. If 1. fails, there exists a solution with $x,y$ distinct regardless.

I have noticed that 1. fails whenever $B = 2A^2 - A - 1$, although I do not know how to prove that this is the only exception or where to go from there.

Comment: how is that possible? n is odd, and (a-1) and (b-1) are both even...

Comment: Agh, it's supposed to be n is the sum of the combination and n-1 is the number that gets factored... This problem is the last step of a larger proof and going back and forth between the different parts I must've gotten it messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $\gcd(a-1, b-1) = 2$, we have both $a-1$ and $b-1$ even. So $(a-1)x + (b-1)y$ is even too, but then this can never equal $n$ since $n=ab$ is odd.